# Java int cast returns 0

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
int i = (int) 0.72;
System.out.println(i);
```

Which yields the following output:

```
0
```

I would of imagined that the variable `i` should have the value of `1` *(since 0.72 > 0.5 => 1)*, why is this not the case?

*(I imagine that when casting to int, it simply cuts of the decimal digits after the comma, not taking into account of rounding up; so I'll probably have to take care of that myself?)*

Comment: Someone needs truncation; others need rounding. Only one rule can apply to a narrowing conversion, and that one rule is truncation.

Comment: What you intended to use, is `Math.round()`

Comment: this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java can help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct, casting to an int will just truncate the number. You can do something like this to get the result you are after:

```
int i = (int)Math.round(0.72);
System.out.println(i);
```

This will print 1 for 0.72 and 0 for 0.28 for example.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you cast a double to int, decimal part is truncated

UPDATE `Math.round` will give your desired output instead of `Math.ceil`:

```
 System.out.println(Math.round(0.72));
// will output 1

 System.out.println(Math.round(0.20));
// will output 0
```

You can use `Math.ceil` :

```
System.out.println(Math.ceil(0.72));
// will output 1
 System.out.println(Math.ceil(0.20));
// will output 1
```

Comment: There is to mention, that `ceil` will always round upwards, not only if `>= .5`

Answer (score 1):

Casting to an int implicity drops the decimal part. That's why you get 0 because anything after the 0 is removed (in your case the 72). If you want to round then look at [Math.round(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)

Answer (score 1):

Explicit cast does a conversion a float/double value to an int variable (which discards the fractional part)

Answer (score 1):

Java does not round-off the number like we do.It simply truncates the decimal part.
If you want to round-off the number use java.lang.Math

Answer (score 1):

Casting `double` to `int` truncates the non-integer portion of the number.

To round numbers as you describe, use [`Math.round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)

Answer (score 0):

As a complete Java beginner, and just in case my experience is useful to someone, I was just making the following mistake:

`int x = (int) Math.random() * 10;`

... which will always set x to 0. Instead, I should've done `int x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);`.

Not much of a Java-know-how specific mistake, but I'll just throw this in case anyone puzzled by this stumbles upon this question.